# Объясните почему click() стоит перед addEventListener('click', () => resolve()), но слушатель всё равно выполнятся?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Этот код мне написал chatGpt

```
function awaitAfterClick(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.click();
    element.addEventListener('click', () => resolve());
});
}
```

Он сказал, что не смотря на то, что element.addEventListener('click', () => resolve()); добавляется после клика он будет выполнен. Я не понимаю почему. Клик уже произошел, как будущий слушатель сможет обработать событие из прошлого?

Comment: В коде и без этого есть ошибка, например `const = document.querySelector(selector)`, это синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: Исправил, переписал с ошибкой

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае нет никакой связи между `element.click();` и `element.addEventListener('click', () => resolve());`

У любого элемента по умолчанию есть обработчик `click`, который ничего не делает. В данном случае `element.click();` вызовет именно его, если до этого не были добавлены какие-то другие обработчики. Именно он и будет вызван.

После этого будет добавлен новый обработчик `element.addEventListener('click', () => resolve());` который завершит `Promise`. Однако выполнен он будет только после следующего клика по элементу.

Поэтому на вопрос *как будущий слушатель сможет обработать событие из прошлого?* - ответ - никак.